# what are the input parameters and return type SBGetScreenLockStatus in iOS springboard framework?

Tags: ios

what are the input parameters and return type SBGetScreenLockStatus in iOS springboard framework

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it's your own answer in the blog. Here is description of parameters and return types: http://www.marekbell.com/?p=137